# How to create multiple ":memory:" databases in sqlite3

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to create multiple in-memory databases with sqlite3 (if possible).
For on-disk databases, I would do:

```
import sqlite3 

db1 = sqlite3.connect('/mnt/tmp/db1.db')
db2 = sqlite3.connect('/mnt/tmp/db2.db')
db3 = sqlite3.connect('/mnt/tmp/db3.db')
```

If I instead do:

```
db1 = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")
db2 = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")
db3 = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")
```

Will this result in three separate in-memory databases? This seems to create three connections to a shared in-memory database, which is not what I want.

I then proceed to create cursors on the databases (on-disk or in-memory) with:

```
cur_db1 = db1.cursor()
cur_db2 = db2.cursor()
cur_db3 = db3.cursor()
```

If multiple in-memory databases are not possible, is my best choice to use RAM-disk databases (as in my first code block), but then to execute `"PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY"` on these connections?

Comment: What do you mean "seems to create"?  What do you do to verify and/or test?

Comment: If I create the three db connections using `"file::memory:?cache=shared"`, then upon trying to execute an `insert` on a table created in one of the databases, I get `OperationalError('database is locked',)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in [online docs](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), specifying a shared cache using the URI format like you are using will cause all connections in the same process to use the same database. If you want three separate in-memory instances, then use a *named* in-memory database using `file:<DB_Name>?mode=memory&cache=shared` as the connection string.

From the webpage...

> If two or more distinct but shareable in-memory databases are needed in a single process, then the mode=memory query parameter can be used with a URI filename to create a named in-memory database:
>
> `rc = sqlite3_open("file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared", &db);`
>
> When an in-memory database is named in this way, it will only share its cache with another connection that uses exactly the same name.